# Prefixing with underscore to remove unused code warning. What am I actually telling the compiler?

Tags: rust, unused-variables

When using a for loop

```
for i in 1..10 {}
```

The compiler tells me to prefix `i` like this: `_i`.

What am I actually conveying by putting the underscore in front of variables or functions?

Comment: The compiler message *tells you exactly what is happening*: `= note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default. to avoid this warning, consider using \`_i\` instead`. It's an unused variable, and an underscore conveys that you don't care that the variable is unused.